# InnerHTML content is different then actually seen on screen

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, innerhtml

I have dynamically created span elements that listen to an onkeyup action.

For example: When a user types into a `textbox`, it should replace the text inside the `<span>` too.

lets say I create `N` elements of span.

`N-1` of then works perfectly, but the ***last one*** does not.

When I use Inspect Element (Chrome browser) and make the call

```
document.getElementById("span...").innerHTML
```

I see the new text, but on screen I still see the old one.

**My code:**
 1. This is the part when i dynamically create the text inputs

```
titleInput.onkeyup = (function () 
{ 
  var inputObject = titleInput; 
  var chartIndex = numberOfTds; return function () {          
  UpdateTitleInMagnifiedView(inputObject, chartIndex); 
} })();
```

1. UpdateTitleInMagnifiedView - function that updates the span elemnts
     document.getElementById("title_magnified_" + chartIndex).innerHTML = inputObject.value;

Comment: post your code,... javascript and HTML here... lets see...

Comment: edit it in the question area